# Drag email from mail.app to create a shortcut, not eml

Tags: mail.app, url

The title is self-explainatory.
Once I succeeded, and there was `.inetloc` file including XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>message:%3CCAODRpat8f6Ca07rDHa+-uq23Cp1nk5E9MEReXbX8YaXfMcu8BA@mail.gmail.com%3E</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But now I can't recall how I did that. When you drag-and-drop an email from a list in Mail.App there is an `.eml` file created, which is totally what I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way of doing this [at Mac OS X Hints here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110111024749663).

1. Open the message in a new window (select it and press <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd>).
2. Drag the proxy icon to the location where you would like the `.inetloc` file.  The proxy icon is the envelope icon in the window's title bar, to the left of the message title.

[image: Mail.app message proxy icon]

Comment: thank you! already found that, but didn't posted, my bad.